# React npm start fails

Tags: reactjs

I have cloned git-repo and tried to start my react project with npm start and i tried npm install but it still don't working. Should i do npm build or? Below is from the terminal!

```
[mån jan 13 21:44:43] Jonathan@Whats next?:~/Udemy/Andrei_Neagoie/The_Complete_Web_Developer_in_2020:_Zero_to_Mastery/Section_19:React.js_+_Redux/robofriends$ npm install

> core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /home/jonteyh/Udemy/Andrei_Neagoie/The_Complete_Web_Developer_in_2020:_Zero_to_Mastery/Section_19:React.js_+_Redux/robofriends/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> core-js@3.2.1 postinstall /home/jonteyh/Udemy/Andrei_Neagoie/The_Complete_Web_Developer_in_2020:_Zero_to_Mastery/Section_19:React.js_+_Redux/robofriends/node_modules/core-js
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.0.7 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.0.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

added 1451 packages from 689 contributors and audited 904902 packages in 195.677s
found 6 vulnerabilities (3 moderate, 3 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

[mån jan 13 21:50:39] Jonathan@Whats next?:~/Udemy/Andrei_Neagoie/The_Complete_Web_Developer_in_2020:_Zero_to_Mastery/Section_19:React.js_+_Redux/robofriends$ npm start

> robofriends@0.1.0 start /home/jonteyh/Udemy/Andrei_Neagoie/The_Complete_Web_Developer_in_2020:_Zero_to_Mastery/Section_19:React.js_+_Redux/robofriends
> react-scripts start

sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! robofriends@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the robofriends@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/jonteyh/.npm/_logs/2020-01-13T20_56_07_120Z-debug.log
```

Comment: react-scripts module is missing

Comment: You can see what npm commands are available to you by looking in the `package.json` file under `scripts`.

Comment: Sameer i am new to react can i download this react-scripts module somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry Sameer was right it was missing react-scripts module and i solved it very easily with just this command down here!

sudo npm install react-scripts -g

To install and after that it worked without any problems!